# Why my React Native Community datetimepicker crashes IOS app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetime, datepicker, expo

I am using `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` `version 7.6.2` in my Expo application and sometimes when the user is picking a `datetime` date (happens once in 10 tries) my app just crash with the mentioned below.

This only happens in IOS, on Android it works fine. I am using "react-native": "0.72.4".

I am out of ideas :/

Here's my code:

```
  const onDateChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate;
    setDate(selectedDate);
    setDateText(formatDate(currentDate)); //Formats date value to string like "2023-12-07"
  };
  
  return(
    <View
    style={{
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      flexDirection: "row",
    }}
  >
    <Text style={fontStyles.baseText(darkMode)}>Születési dátum</Text>

    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.textBox_DatePicker(darkMode)}
      onPress={()=>{setShow(!show)}}
    >
      {!dateText ? (
        <Icon
          name="calendar-plus-o"
          size={moderateScale(20)}
          color={darkMode ? color_theme_dark.mainGreen : color_theme_light.mainGreen}
        />
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.pickedDate(darkMode)}>{dateText}</Text>
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  
  {show && (
    <DateTimePicker
      value={date}
      mode={"date"}
      display={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "spinner" : "default"}
      onChange={onDateChange}
      style={styles.datePicker}
      textColor={darkMode ? "white" : "black"}
      theme={'light'}
    />
  )}
  )
```

And here is the error log that gets printed when the app crashes:

```
ERROR  Your app just crashed. See the error below.
NSGenericException: *** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x2836ee070> was mutated while being enumerated.
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018193bc74 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 601204
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000199167ee4 objc_exception_throw + 56       
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181a06120 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 1429792
  3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a1df1c 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 14917404
  4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184a026f4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 14804724
  5   eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  6   eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  7   eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da5bf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1842160
  9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001840bc620 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5080608
  10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818b609c EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 53404
  11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818f1ad4 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 297684
  12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840448d4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 4589780
  13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183ffca1c 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 4295196
  14  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  15  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  16  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  17  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  18  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  19  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  20  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  21  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  22  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  23  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da5bf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1842160
  24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840bc620 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5080608
  25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818b609c EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 53404
  26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818f1ad4 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 297684
  27  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840448d4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 4589780
  28  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da5bf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1842160
  29  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840bc620 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5080608
  30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818b609c EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 53404
  31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818f1ad4 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 297684
  32  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840448d4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 4589780
  33  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  34  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  35  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  36  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  37  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  38  eKisllat                            0x0000000103fa7440 -[RCTView hitTest:withEvent:] + 
616
  39  eKisllat                            0x0000000103f675b0 -[RCTRootContentView hitTest:withEvent:] + 96
  40  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da5bf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1842160
  41  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840bc620 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5080608
  42  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818b609c EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 53404
  43  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818f1ad4 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 297684
  44  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840448d4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 4589780
  45  eKisllat                            0x0000000103f69e5c -[RCTRootView hitTest:withEvent:] + 96
  46  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da5bf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1842160
  47  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840bc620 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5080608
  48  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818b609c EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 53404
  49  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818f1ad4 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 297684
  50  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840448d4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 4589780
  51  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183c4aa10 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 420368
  52  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da5bf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1842160
  53  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840bc620 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5080608
  54  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818b609c EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 53404
  55  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818f1ad4 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 297684
  56  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840448d4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 4589780
  57  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183c4b3d4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 422868
  58  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da5bf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1842160
  59  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840bc620 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5080608
  60  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818b609c EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 53404
  61  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818f1ad4 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 297684
  62  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840448d4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 4589780
  63  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da5bf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1842160
  64  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183ca8aa8 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 805544
  65  UIKitCore                           0x000000018411c5f8 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5473784
  66  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183d67e58 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1588824
  67  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183e874e4 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 2766052
  68  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183da31dc 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1831388
  69  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183c2a130 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 287024
  70  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183c2a668 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 288360
  71  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184ad7258 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 15675992
  72  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183d42f08 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1437448
  73  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183d495fc 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1463804
  74  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183d3faf0 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1424112
  75  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183d44f0c 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 1445644
  76  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018195c448 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 734280
  77  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018196c578 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 800120
  78  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818ae734 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 22324
  79  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818b3e08 EEC1287D-059B-38C8-9BC1-58A0C8B1E6C2 + 44552
  80  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001818c7174 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572      
  81  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001a2402988 GSEventRunModal + 160
  82  UIKitCore                           0x00000001840c9a88 9D301877-2593-385C-8F72-F075AA0B48FA + 5134984
  83  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183e62f78 UIApplicationMain + 336
  84  eKisllat                            0x0000000102da50bc main + 96
  85  dyld                                0x000000010a3384d0 start + 444
```

[image: GIF]